# Google chrome gives Connection was reset

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, google-chrome, dns

When ever I open a website it gives me,

> Connection was reset error.

After refreshing the page for nearly five times, then it loads the page.

Did anyone face this issue? Have any solutions?

I tried to add the Google DNS server in my IPV4 properties, but it didn't help.

I have Google fiber internet connection if this helps.

Comment: Does this problem arise in any other browser? Do ping, nslookup, tracert commands work?

Comment: Yes in firefox and internet explorer. when i did ping to a particular website. It was reachable and I tried on 4 diff machines same gives the "the conneciton was reset" error

Comment: Are your web connections going through a proxy? This same issue happens to me when our proxy server is acting up.

Comment: I checked that too. I have contacted google fiber guys to see if they were filtering my traffic. They said no. I have removed "Use proxy server to you LAN" from Internet options but that didn't help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue. The problem was some of the sites doesn't work with IPV6 protocol. So I went ahead and turned off ipv6 from network settings. Restarted my PC, all the sites started to load with out any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Can you believe for a certain site, all it took was clearing the browser's accumulated cookies for that site from previous visits! Poof... no more Connection Reset.

Answer (score -1):

Go to **Wi-Fi Settings** and perform a **Network reset**.

Restart your computer and re-connect to the internet.

See if that helps you to fix the issue.

Comment: I have no internet connection problem issue. the issue is with the google chrome which gives connections reset error.